# How do I create Jenkins job Specific Environment Variable?

Tags: jenkins

There is a way to setup environment variables in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties. But I don’t want to use this approach as it will expose my variable to other jobs.

I want to create environment variables which are accessible by only one specific Jenkins Job.

Please can someone suggest how can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this plugin will help you

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: Thanks Chaitu, It helped me.